# How to make background colour change on hover to happen from top to bottom like ink-fill

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How to hover on the button to change bg from top to bottom like ink fill.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/48pOA2T7Cg

```
    <button class="group relative whitespace-nowrap">

  <span class="absolute rounded-2xl border border-black bg-black px-4 py-2 text-white duration-[2000ms] hover:bg-white hover:text-black hover:transition-colors hover:duration-[1000ms] ease-in-out">See My Work</span>


  </button>
```

Comment: If you want to do it ONLY with tailwind, you'll have to extend it to add your own custom animation (in your case a background image that animates down). https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation

Comment: Plain Css will also work. You got any code examples?